# Accessing a file over FTP

Tags: ftp

I have a file on a centos 7 server that I need to access over FTP. Not transfer, just read every time.

For more details, it's a kdbx encrypted password file, that I need to access from local machines everytime I open keepass (it uses that file to get multiple accounts and passwords to other servers).

Basically, I need to give keepass a path to the file. But the file is on a centos 7 server.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why FTP? SMB or Webdav both seem more appropriate.

Comment: It has to be FTP unforunatly

Comment: So, CurlFtpFS on Linux or FTPdrive from Windows?  Or are you looking at installing the ftp server?